Ошибка в получении данных VK Api
Подскажите почему возникает ошибка "Ошибка при получении данных"? Ничего не отдается хотя id и токен ввожу правильно
<?php
$group_id = '******';
$access_token = '********';
$count = 5; // Количество постов

$url = "https://api.vk.com/method/wall.get?owner_id=-$group_id&count=$count&access_token=$access_token&v=5.131";
$response = file_get_contents($url);
$data = json_decode($response, true);

if (isset($data['response']) && isset($data['response']['items'])) {
$posts = $data['response']['items'];

foreach ($posts as $post) {
// Выводим текст поста
echo $post['text'] . '
';

// Дополнительные действия с постом
// Например, вывод изображений, комментариев и т.д.
}
} else {
echo 'Ошибка при получении данных';
}
?>


Давно ли file_get_contents осуществляет http-запрос? вам наверное нужен curl

@noobaster точно, спасибо огромное!!!

@noobaster всю жизнь им пользуюсь и ничего, а тут внезапно нельзя данные получить.... вот приехали... Я понимаю ещё нельзя POST запрос сделать или PUT. Но вот из URL через GET - запросто

@Arcadiy в $data в любом случае должно что-то быть, даже банально ошибка доступа

@АлексейШиманский Ошибка №27

@Arcadiy посмотрите что это за ошибка в вк. мне лично чисто номер ничего не даёт

@АлексейШиманский нельзя использовать метод wall.get

Где это вы такое вычитали? А я смотрю сюда https://dev.vk.com/ru/reference/errors и написано "27
Ключ доступа сообщества недействителен."

@АлексейШиманский ну я не знал что так можно) поэтому там знак вопроса есть :-)

@АлексейШиманский https://dev.vk.com/ru/method/wall.get

@АлексейШиманский "error_code":27
"error_msg":"Group authorization failed: method is unavailable with group auth."

@Arcadiy ну да, этот метод можно вызвать с ключом доступа пользователя. или с сервисным ключом доступа, а не с ключом сообщества. О чём написано в самом начале метода

@noobaster тогда почитайте доки. https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.file-get-contents.php  . там есть примеры. даже больше того скажу, там есть пример HTTP запроса с отсылкой заголовков ;-)  То есть даже POST можно отправить (о чём я подзабыл даже)

@АлексейШиманский, спасибо) уже глянул)
